# Adding timeline marks in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating an application that can be used to analyze videos. One option it should have is to mark events. If the user has marked an event, the timeline should get an colored piece in it that represents that mark (just like YouTube, where it shows an ad).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried writing any code?  My first instinct would be to create an AnchorPane, and add a small rectangular Node to it for each mark, with the Node's translateX set to a value that proportionally matches the mark's value.

Comment: @VGR I've started with the player itself, but I wanted to do a quick check on how I would do this. You just confirmed my thoughts, so thanks for that! :)